# How to set the `app_settings`'s `AuthenticationMethod` to `username_email`?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

In my project I use the `allauth`, and in my custom LoginSerializer's `validate` method:

```
    if 'allauth' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        from allauth.account import app_settings

        # Authentication through email
        if app_settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD == app_settings.AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL:
            user = self._validate_email(email, password)

        # Authentication through username
        if app_settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD == app_settings.AuthenticationMethod.USERNAME:
            user = self._validate_username(username, password)
```

you see there are `app_settings.AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL` and `app_settings.AuthenticationMethod.USERNAME` types.

I read the source code I found the:

[image]

There has another type `USERNAME_EMAIL` :

```
class AppSettings(object):

    class AuthenticationMethod:
        USERNAME = 'username'
        EMAIL = 'email'
        USERNAME_EMAIL = 'username_email'
```

Where can I set the allauth use the AuthenticationMethod.USERNAME_EMAIL?

Answer (score 1):

configure the `ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD` in your `settings.py` it will works:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
```

please be carefully, don't set `AUTHENTICATION_METHOD`.

You can find more detail in [official document](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).